# How to find the roots of a transcendental equation that depends on Bessel functions?

Tags: equation-solving

[image: I need to find the roots for m of this equation. Where l=10^{-4}mm and L=10^{-6}.]

I am very new in wolfram mathematica, so i am having trouble in trying to find the roots for this
transcendental equation. I am looking for roots of m. Acctually the first non zero value for m. Here J is the Bessel function on first kind and N is the Bessel function of second kind. I have tried some codes but it did not work.

Comment: Please type your equation in Mathematica format. Do not post a picture.

Comment: Try `Solve[eqn && 11000 < m < 100000, m]`.

Answer (score 3):

In Mathematica, a Bessel function of the second kind is [`BesselY`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/BesselY.html)

```
Clear["Global`*"]

l = 10^-4; L = 10^-6;

eqn = -BesselY[2, m*L]*BesselJ[1, m*L]*
     BesselJ[2, m*(l + L)]*BesselY[1, m*(l + L)] -
    BesselJ[2, m*L]*BesselJ[1, m*L]*
     BesselY[2, m*(l + L)]*BesselJ[1, m*(l + L)] +
    BesselY[2, m*L]*BesselY[1, m*L]*
     BesselJ[2, m*(l + L)]*BesselJ[1, m*(l + L)] +
    BesselJ[2, m*L]*BesselJ[1, m*L]*
     BesselY[2, m*(l + L)]*BesselY[1, m*(l + L)] == 0;

LogLinearPlot[Evaluate@eqn[[1]], {m, 0, 100000},
 PlotPoints -> 100, MaxRecursion -> 2]
```

[image]

```
LogLinearPlot[Evaluate@eqn[[1]], {m, 3*^4, 100000}]
```

[image]

The plot provides initial estimates to use with [`FindRoot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindRoot.html)

```
sol = FindRoot[eqn, {m, #}] & /@ {3.5*^4, 5*^4, 7*^4, 10^5}

{{m -> 37949.1}, {m -> 50847.7}, {m -> 69498.8}, {m -> 100805.}}
```